# Cannot save datetime to MongoDB using Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot and I try to save some date in MongoDB. My input date is

> "2017-08-14T12:59"

I get this error while saving:

```
 Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Failed to parse Date value '2017-08-14T12:59': Can not parse date "2017-08-14T12:59.000Z": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'', parsing fails (leniency? null); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to parse Date value '2017-08-14T12:59': Can not parse date "2017-08-14T12:59.000Z": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'', parsing fails (leniency? null) (through reference chain:
```

In my POJO i tried like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using= CustomDateDeserialize.class)
private Date inputDateTime;
```

and I've implemented Deserializer like this :

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser paramJsonParser,
            DeserializationContext paramDeserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String str = paramJsonParser.getText().trim();
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
        return paramDeserializationContext.parseDate(str);
    }
```

What else I miss here? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify format in your deserializer.

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");

any way simpledatetimeformat is not thread safe. if you java8 use DateTimeFormat.

Comment: i tried this also but i am getting JSON parse error: Failed to parse Date value '2017-08-14T12:59': Can not parse date "2017-08-14T12:59.000Z": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'', parsing fails (leniency? null);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try `Instant` library

```
@Field("your_db_id_name")
private Instant inputDateTime;

public void setInputDateTime(Instant inputDateTime) {
    this.inputDateTime = inputDateTime;
}

public void getInputDateTime() {
     return inputDateTime;
}
```

You can set Filed by using `Instant.now()`

Comment: nice one i will try this

Comment: @Rohitesh If this solves your problem upvote and mark as right answer. it will be valuable for others.